# What is the correct format of populating a JSON object with a nested array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I'm trying to create a JSON object with a nested array of JSON objects. What is the correct format of this?

Here is an example what I am trying to create:

```
    {
    "reviewCount": 96,
    "reviews": [
        {"name": "Sean Steinman", "date": "reviewed 2 weeks ago", "reviewContent": "Fantastic Service"},
        {"name": "Ryan Lundell", "date": "reviewed in the last week", "reviewContent":"Ask for Scott!"}
    ]
}
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
var reviewObj = {
   reviewCount: reviews.length,
   reviews: [{name: , date: , reviewContent:}]
}
```

After I initialize  it, I will fill it with a for loop that runs through an existing array of strings.

**CLARIFICATION:**

The array that I'm using to populate the JSON object is:

```
[
  "\nSean Steinman\nreviewed 2 weeks ago\n Fantastic Service\n",
  "\nRyan Lundell\nreviewed in the last week\n Ask for Scott!\n• • •\n"
]
```

So I'm creating a new array in my `for` with `tmpArr = reviews[i].split('/n');`, and then **where I'm getting stuck** is how to stick that into the JSON object as an object.

Comment: The first code block shows the correct JSON format. What exactly is the question?

Comment: `{name: , date: , reviewContent:}` is of course invalid syntax. But it's unclear to me what you are asking for. Basically the JSON encoded and the object literal you want to create have exactly the same structure. Maybe you want `reviews: reviews` instead? What's the problem you have? Keep in mind to call `JSON.stringify` at the end to get your JSON.

Comment: Correction: The first code block almost shows the correct JSON format. The property names (`name`, `date`, and `reviewContent`) should be wrapped in double quotes.

Comment: I'd suggest making a separate object for the array of reviews like `reviewDetailObj = {name: '', date: '', reviewContent: ''}` and populating `reviews` in the loop dynamically with `reviewDetailObj`s

Comment: Sorry guys, see edits to question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you're not building a "JSON" object. You're just building an object. It's not JSON until you JSON-encode it. `{"name": "bob"}` is not JSON, it's an object literal. `'{"name": "bob"}'`, the **string**, is JSON.

Second, you cannot loop inside an object literal, which is what your second code example seems to indicate you're trying to do. Instead, you need to initialize you `reviews` property to an empty array, and *then* loop and append items to the array.

```
var reviews = [
  "\nSean Steinman\nreviewed 2 weeks ago\n Fantastic Service\n",
  "\nRyan Lundell\nreviewed in the last week\n Ask for Scott!\n• • •\n"
];

var reviewObj = {
  reviewCount: reviews.length,
  reviews: []
}

reviews.forEach(function(line) {
  var review = line.split("\n");
  reviewObj.reviews.push({name: review[0], date: review[1], reviewContent: review[2]});
});
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, I added to the question to clarify some things.

Comment: Running to a meeting, I'll check out your answer when I get back. I'm a n00b so thanks again!

Comment: Just implemented your suggestions. Looking good, but the only thing is that all of the content (name, date, content) is in ``review[0]`` of the ``review`` array.  ``review[1]`` and ``review[2]`` are both empty.

Comment: @novicePrgrmr  Then you've misrepresented your inputs.

Comment: Actually, figured out that we were trying to splitting on ``/n`` instead of ``\n``.